# associative php array from html data attributes and texts

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div class='title' data-x='car'>black</div>
<div class='title' data-x='home'>white</div>
<div class='title' data-x='train'>gold</div>
```

what is the easyest way to get an associative array on php side:

```
$arr = ['car' => 'black', 'home' => 'white', 'train' => 'gold'];
```

Comment: How are you going to get that data? Do you want to send that data to PHP? Do you want to scrape a page with PHP?

Comment: so the html is not generated by php - but you want to create an array of the html? - in that case, you can send the variables to a php script or function, with either POST or GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proposal that I have:

1. Use jQuery to add and map the data in one object.
2. Use Ajax for sending the data
3. Take all posted variables and transfer it into your array

Code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = {};
    $('.title').map(function(){
        data[$(this).data('x')] = $(this).html();
    }).get();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'whatever.php',
        data: data,
        success: (response)=>{
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' data-x='car'>black</div>
<div class='title' data-x='home'>white</div>
<div class='title' data-x='train'>gold</div>
```

And the file `whatever.php`:

```
$arr = [];
if($_POST) {
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
        $arr[$k] = $v;
    }
    var_dump($arr);
}
```

Here is the console output:

```
array(3) {
    ["car"]=>string(5) "black"
    ["home"]=>string(5) "white"
    ["train"]=>string(4) "gold"
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Is there any shorter way to create array on js side, like `var arr = collect($('.title').attr('data-x'))`

Comment: `$('.title').map(function(){data[$(this).data('x')] = $(this).html();}).get();` is the closer that I know as `$('.title')` is an array of element with the class `.title`, and there is not that much ways to combine `data('x')` and the element `.html()`. But ask this on another question and I might jump on that and work my a$s hard on it ^^!